# Calculate infinite summation of sin(x)/x

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you calculate the infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(i)}{i}$? According to Wolfram Alpha, the value of the sum is $\frac{\pi - 1}{2}$, but it does not tell me the method by which it gets this result.

Comment: Try the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula)?

Comment: @HansLundmark, do you think you could elaborate a bit in an answer? Thanks.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242280/what-is-the-sum-over-a-shifted-sinc-function. (Set $y=0$ and consider only half of the sum, minus the zeroth term.)

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/838046):

> Using the power series
>   $$
> -\log(1-z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k}
> $$
>   we get
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(k)}{k}
> &=\frac1{2i}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ik}-e^{-ik}}{k}\\
> &=\frac1{2i}\left[-\log(1-e^i)+\log(1-e^{-i})\right]\\
> &=\frac1{2i}\log(-e^{-i})\\
> &=\frac{\pi-1}{2}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   That is, since $1-e^{-i}$ is in the first quadrant and $1-e^i$ is in the fourth, the imaginary part of $-\log(1-e^i)+\log(1-e^{-i})$ is between $0$ and $\pi$.

Convergence is guaranteed by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) and convergence to the value expected by [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Comment: We are evaluating a power series on the boundary of its convergence disk, or, equivalently, we are stating that the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave is pointwise convergent at $x=1$. That is true, but it needs a bit of extra care to be justified in full rigor (this applies to my old answer in the duplicate thread, too).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: These converge by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) and converge to the value expected by [Abel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). I have mentioned these in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two summations $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k)}{k}\qquad \text{and} \qquad C=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)}{k}$$
$$C+iS=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)+i \sin(k)}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i k}} k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{i})^ k} k=-\log \left(1-e^i\right)$$
$$C-iS=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(k)-i \sin(k)}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-i k}} k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-i})^ k} k=-\log \left(1-e^{-i}\right)$$ Expanding the logarithm
$$C+i S=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\sin ^2(1)+(1-\cos (1))^2\right)+i \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (1)}{1-\cos (1)}\right)$$ $$C+i S=-\frac{1}{2} \log (2-2 \cos (1))+i \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$C-i S=-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\sin ^2(1)+(1-\cos (1))^2\right)-i \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (1)}{1-\cos (1)}\right)$$
$$C-i S=-\frac{1}{2} \log (2-2 \cos (1))+i \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$$
$$C=\frac{(C+iS)+(C-iS)}2=-\frac{1}{2} \log (2-2 \cos (1))$$
$$S=\frac{(C+iS)-(C-iS)}{2i}=\frac{1}{2} (\pi -1)$$